# Filter child documents and retrieve the parent+child document

Tags: solr

I have a simple document in my Solr server:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "dad",
    "_childDocuments_": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Alice"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Bob"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to filter this document to retrieve only the "Alice" document, along with the parent document, excluding the other child, "Bob".

Expected result:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "dad",
    "_childDocuments_": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Alice"
        }
    ]
}
```

For this, I'm using the following query:

```
q: name:Alice
fl: *, [child parentFilter=*:* limit=10]
```

The problem is: this filter returns only the Alice child document, without the corresponding dad parent document.

How can I fix this search? I've tried using `parentFilter=type:dad`, like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587990/how-can-you-retrieve-a-full-nested-document-in-solr), but this query throws [an error](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/other-parsers.html#block-join-children-query-parser) that I couldn't understand:

> Parent query must not match any docs besides parent filter. Combine them as must (+) and must-not (-) clauses to find a problem doc. docID=0

Also, if I filter with:

```
q: type:dad name:Alice
fl: *, [child parentFilter=*:* limit=10]
```

I will get two documents: dad + Alice and not one document with dad->Alice

Comment: How about `[child ... childFilter=name:Alice]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `childFilter` along with the `parentFilter`:

```
q= type:dad
fl= *, [child parentFilter=type:dad childFilter=name:Alice limit=10]
```

Result:

```json
"response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": ["dad"],
            "_version_": 1603065478506348544,
            "type_str": ["dad"],
            "_childDocuments_": [
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": ["Alice"],
                    "_version_": 1603065478506348544,
                    "name_str": ["Alice"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```